# How to compile C++ dependencies during pip install?

Tags: python, pip, packaging, setuptools

I want to make my python code pip-able. However, my code depends on another library which isn't pip-able. So, somehow I need to compile the source code when a user calls `pip install`.

How can I do that? I haven't been able to find a good reference via simple Google searches.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend taking a look at how llvmlite solves this problem. The idea is to use custom `cmdclass`s  in `setup.py` that calls your other build system. In llvmlite, they call out to CMake, for example.

See: https://github.com/numba/llvmlite/blob/master/setup.py