# How to declare external libraries bindings dependencies in Python

Tags: python, opencv, pip, setuptools

There are two ways in Python to impose dependencies (that are resolved by `pip`):

- `requirements.txt` file and
- `setup.py` configuration with `setuptools`

my question is related to the case when you have Python bindings shipped with external C++ libraries (i.e. `OpenCV`) in form of shared library (i.e. `cv2.so`) to be appended to `PYTHONPATH`.

How should I manage the dependency? Simply notifying users in the `README`? Or are there any 'better' or 'official' best practices?

Comment: Still not finding notable informations about that. Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30657841/1334711